# How to convert an Option[String]to List [Int]in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option

I'm able to convert Option[String] to List[String] with the following code :

```
 def convertOptionToListString(a: Option[String]): List[String] = {
    return a.toList.flatMap(_.split(",")) // ex : ("value1", "value2", "value3", etc)
  }
```

But how can i convert Option[String] to List[Int] so at the end i can have list with integers : (1,3,5). My Option[String] will looks like this : Some("1,3,5")

Note that the values **1,3,5** comes from **params.get("ids")** sent from an url and **params.get** is an **Option[String]**

```
val params = request.queryString.map { case (k, v) => k -> v(0) }
```

Thanks

Comment: `Some("1","3","5")` isn't a `Option[String]`.  It's a `Option(String,String,String)`.  Which do you mean?

Comment: Yes it is : The values 1,3,5 comes from params.get("ids") sent from an url and params.get is an Option[String]

Comment: `scala> Some("1","3","5")`  
`res40: Some[(String, String, String)] = Some((1,3,5))`

Comment: Maybe you mean `Some("1,3,5")` ? Or are the quotes around each number actually part of the String?

Comment: Yes Dylan i meant Some("1,3,5"). Sorry

Comment: One note, using `return` here is unnecessary and it is generally discouraged - see https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html for a good explanation of why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val a: Option[String] = Some("1,3,5")
val l = a.toList.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(_.toInt)
```

Comment: Thank you dhg. I'm learning scala and this trick will help me a lot :)

Comment: This will not work for non numeric characters 
_.toInt will throw NumberFormatException

Comment: @franki3xe, It also won't work if the input comes in pipe-delimited instead of comma-delimited, and it won't work if the input comes written in roman numerals, or in a secret code where integers are replaced by letters.  If you know what the input looks like, why would you add unnecessary complexity to guard against something that's not going to happen?

Comment: Hey dhg, i wanted to up vote again but i'm not allowed for now !!! It's weird cause i already up voted yesteray and now it came to 0 !!!

Answer (score 2):

`Scala 2.13` introduced [`String::toIntOption`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/StringOps.html#toIntOption:Option[Int]).

Combined with a `flatMap`, we can safely cast `String`s into `Int`s and eliminate malformed inputs:

```
List("1", "2", "abc").flatMap(_.toIntOption)
// List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `List[String]` to `List[Int]`, skipping unparseable values, then you can use `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try

List("1", "2", "3").flatMap(x => Try(x.toInt).toOption)
res0: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

List("1", "2", "abc").flatMap(x => Try(x.toInt).toOption)
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

Comment: A regex and `collect` would give you similar behavior: `val IntRe = "(\\d+)"; xs.collect { case Re(n) => n.toInt }`

Answer (score 0):

From where you are, you just need to map `toInt` over it.  But your order of operations is kind of weird.  It's like you're using `toList` just to satisfy the type.  `toList` is one of those smelly functions where if you're using it you're probably abusing something.

The logic that reads the best is that if you have a `Some`, then process it, otherwise you just default to the empty list (I'm guessing):

```
option match {
  case Some(str) => str.split(",").map(_.toInt)
  case None => List()
}
```

Or:

```
option.map(_.split(",").map(_.toInt)).getOrElse(List())
```